# Windows Forms (Powershell) | Message Box showing up twice

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

I hope you're all good!

The message box below is showing up twice and I don't know why.
This happens only when I change between buttons.

Could you help me understand why?

```
 $ActiveDirectory.controls.AddRange(@($ToolsPanel,$ADToolsPanel,$VerUsersLabel,$VerUsersCancel,$VerUsersOK,$VerUsersTextBox,$FerLabelPanel))

$VerUsersOK.Add_Click({
    if ($VerUsersTextBox.Textlength -eq 0){
     
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Não foi introduzida nenhuma informação',$ButtonText,'OK','Error')

    }  
    
})

})


$AlButton.Add_Click({


$ActiveDirectory.controls.Clear()
$AlUsersOptionsGroupbox.controls.AddRange(@($AlUsersUnlockCheckBox,$AlUsersDisableCheckBox,$AlUsersMustChangeCheckBox,$AlUsersEnableCheckBox))
$ActiveDirectory.controls.AddRange(@($ToolsPanel,$ADToolsPanel,$AlPasswordLabel,$AlPasswordTextBox,$AlUsersLabel,$AlUsersTextBox,$AlOKButton,$AlCancelButton,$AlCPasswordLabel,$AlCPasswordTextBox,$AlUsersOptionsGroupbox))

$AlOKButton.Add_Click({

    if (($AlUsersTextBox.TextLength -eq 0) -or ($AlPasswordTextBox.TextLength -eq 0) -or ($AlCPasswordTextBox.TextLength -eq 0)){

            $ButtonText = $AlButton.text
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Não foi introduzida nenhuma informação',$ButtonText,'OK','Error')

    }
})

})

[void]$ActiveDirectory.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: looks like `$AlOKButton.Add_Click` is inside `$AlButton.Add_Click({`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, you are nesting `$AlOKButton.Add_Click` within `$AlButton.Add_Click`. Each time `$AlButton` is clicked you will add a listener to `$AlOKButton`. If you click `$AlButton` 10 times, the message box will show up 10 times.

```
$AlButton.Add_Click({
  $ActiveDirectory.controls.Clear()
  $AlUsersOptionsGroupbox.controls.AddRange(@($AlUsersUnlockCheckBox,$AlUsersDisableCheckBox,$AlUsersMustChangeCheckBox,$AlUsersEnableCheckBox))
  $ActiveDirectory.controls.AddRange(@($ToolsPanel,$ADToolsPanel,$AlPasswordLabel,$AlPasswordTextBox,$AlUsersLabel,$AlUsersTextBox,$AlOKButton,$AlCancelButton,$AlCPasswordLabel,$AlCPasswordTextBox,$AlUsersOptionsGroupbox))
})

$AlOKButton.Add_Click({
  if (($AlUsersTextBox.TextLength -eq 0) -or ($AlPasswordTextBox.TextLength -eq 0) -or ($AlCPasswordTextBox.TextLength -eq 0)){
    $ButtonText = $AlButton.text
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Não foi introduzida nenhuma informação',$ButtonText,'OK','Error')
  }
})
```